# git-secret reveal causes changes to pubring.kbx file - Why?

Tags: git, git-secret

I'm trying to understand the git-secret workflow.

This was the scenario:

- Teammate added my gpg key via **git-secret tell** and re-encrypted the secret files + pushed them.
- I can **reveal** these files, reencrypt them via **git-secret hide** and see that after reencryption (hide) that other teammates should be able to access these files because they are listed in **git-secret whoknows** -> works nicely!

I noticed that just after executing **git-secret reveal** the **pubring.kbx** changed. I dont understand why this would be the case. Am i not just decrypting files?

Why would revealing information cause changes to the keyring?
Do i need to commit these changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured different git-secret versions might be the cause of this. When inspecting the kbx file with kbxutils (https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/kbxutil.html) we could see there were only changes to the header - an empty blob was removed. The keys inside were unchanged.

So commiting should be okay and not cause any conflict, but different git-secret versions by other teammates may cause the keyring to be changed again.